# Three former players of a sport

Tags: knowledge, visual, sports

- *They are 3 former players of a sport from 3 different continents.*
- *They host coronation every year at 3 different locations.*

[image]

---

***What are the names of those 3 players?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three players are

> Rod Laver, Philippe Chartrier and Arthur Ashe

Reasoning

> The finals of the Australian Open, French Open and US Open in tennis are played at the Rod Laver Arena, Court Philippe Chartrier and Arthur Ashe Stadium, respectively

The images correspond to

> The cities which host the events
>  1. Mel (Gibson) + (Jason) Bourne = Melbourne
>  2. Paris (Hilton) = Paris
>  3. New (Zealand) + (Alvin) York = New York